# Performance issue with PivotItem swipe gesture containing ListBox with data binding

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

I've been trying to figure out how to improve the performance of my pivot control which has 4 PivotItems each has listbox with data bind in C#. The loading time has been reduced with BackgroundWorker but first two swipes are always laggy even when all background tasks are executed. 4 seconds of lag is unacceptable. I thought it might have been caused by the listbox itemtemplate which looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MetroList">
  <Grid MinHeight="120">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="190"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="230"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Width="190"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding connectingLines}" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Margin="0,12" VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid Margin="6,0,0,6">
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding LineColor}" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineNumber}" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="8,0" FontSize="24" Margin="0,5,0,3" MinWidth="50" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

      <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
    <Ellipse Width="20"
      Height="20"
      Fill="White"
      StrokeThickness="3"
      Stroke="#FF222378"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Margin="6,0,0,0"
                 Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF222378"
      Width="8"
      Height="3"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
      VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-1,0,0,0" />
    <TextBlock
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
      Text="{Binding stopName}"
      FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold"
      FontWeight="Bold"
      Foreground="#1E1B6E"
      x:Name="StationName"
      FontSize="32"
      Width="200"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Margin="12,6,0,10"
      LineHeight="32"
            Tag="{Binding stopId}"
            Tap="StationName_Tap"
            Grid.Column="2"
                        />
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I've tried cancelling out the ListBox as it was added recently just before the app has the performance problem. But it only reduce the lag time by a few miliseconds. I also tried setting the VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode to recycling just in case but that didn't do anything. Anything I can do to make a better user experience? I heard of loading PivotItem content when it is needed but could not find anything useful from google as most articles either use pivot.loadedpivotitem or pivotitem.loaded event and both didn't help to eliminate the lag.

---

Edit: I realize even though the background thread is working, somehow the ui thread is affected. the page is loaded but you can do nothing to it like swiping until the data bind is completed. and the gestures still lag after that.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with Loading might be because of a huge ItemsSource. You can try to perform Incremental scrolling in your app ([ISupportIncrementalLoading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701916)). Loading less items initially and load remaining items on Demand.